# Split string by spaces and double quotes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I am trying to split a string in Javascript by spaces and double quotes("), but with a special condition: two quotes match only if the first is preceded by whitespace/start of string and the second is followed by whitespace or end of string.

Some examples:

- `"a "b cd"` becomes `['a "b cd']`
- `"a b" cd"` becomes `['a b', 'cd"']`
- `"a "b" "x"" cd"` becomes `['a "b', 'x"', 'cd"']`

Note that quotes which don't obey the above condition remain in their correspondent atoms.

I have a regex which splits by spaces and grouped quotes, but i can't quite figure out one that does what I said.

`/(?:[^\s"]+|"[^"]*")+/g` splits quotes 2 by 2, but that is no good.

Comment: Where is the regexp pattern you have so far?

Comment: A split using regex won't help you to achieve that.

Comment: i've edited the answer with what i have

Comment: Will the closing double quote always be preceded by something other than a space? Are there any characters that the strings are guaranteed not to contain?

Comment: @PSkocik No, not necessarily. To put it simpler, a quote is closed by the first following quote followed by whitespace. If no such quote exists, it is closed by the first space/end of string.
The string can contain any character.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should satisfy your requirements:-

> ((^|\s)".*?(\w|$)")

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more or less manual solution:

```js
function split(s){
  var s = ' '+s+' ';
  var OUT = 0, IN = 1;
  var chunk = "";
  var results = [];
  var state = OUT;
  var length = s.length;

  for(var i=0; i<length; ++i){
    if(state === OUT){
      if(s[i]===' ' && s[i+1] === '"'){
        i++; state = IN; chunk="";  continue;
      }else {
        chunk+=s[i];
      }
    }else if(state === IN ){
      if(s[i]==='"' &&  s[i+1] === ' '){
        i++; state = OUT; results.push(chunk); chunk="";
        if(s[i+1] === '"'){
          i++; state = IN; continue;
        }
      }else {
        chunk+=s[i];
      }
    }
  }
  chunk.replace(/ $/,'');
  if(chunk.length !== 0){
    results.push(chunk);
  }
  return results;
}

['"a "b cd"', '"a b" cd"', '"a "b" "x"" cd"'].forEach(function(s){
  var result = s + ' => ' + "[ '" +split(s).join("', '") + "' ]" + '</br>\n';
  document.write(result);
 });
```

(There might be a better way to `inspect` javascript arrays than what I'm doing there with the `join` method.)